# SQL query - need improvement

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a SQL statement like following, I only have around 20000 records in tableA and 1000 in tableB, but the query takes around 5 seconds, is there any simple way to improve the query speed, thanks!!
(please note that there could be more than two tables to UNION)

I think the performance bottleneck doesn't result from 'UNION', if I just query from tableA, the time is almost the same, any ideas??

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * FROM tableA 
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT * FROM tableB) AS table 
 WHERE id >= 1
 AND deleted = '0' 
 ORDER BY time DESC, id DESC 
 LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: How many rows match the conditions?

Comment: Why do you have a table design where you have two tables with identical structures and you need to query both of them? Could you not reorganise your tables so you only need one table?

Answer (score 3):

One way is to remove the subquery and move the conditions closer to the tables:

```
(SELECT *
 FROM tableA
 WHERE id >= 1 AND deleted = '0'
) UNION ALL
(SELECT *
 FROM tableB
 WHERE id >= 1 AND deleted = '0'
) 
ORDER BY time DESC, id DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

Then create two indexes:

```
create index tableA_deleted_id on tableA(deleted, id);
create index tableB_deleted_id on tableB(deleted, id);
```

Comment: Have you tried this query in SQLite? I'm getting a syntax error on those parens.

Comment: You need to put a `SELECT * FROM` before the first paren I guess.

Answer (score 0):

View the execution plan and see what's happening. If you look at [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/d9e77/1) you'll see notable differences in how it evaluates.

Before indexes:

```
SEARCH TABLE tableA USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid>?) (~25000 rows)
USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
SEARCH TABLE tableB USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid>?) (~25000 rows)
USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
COMPOUND SUBQUERIES 1 AND 2 (UNION ALL)
```

After indexes:

```
SEARCH TABLE tableA USING INDEX IX_tableA (deleted=?) (~3 rows)
USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
SEARCH TABLE tableB USING INDEX IX_tableB (deleted=?) (~3 rows)
USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
COMPOUND SUBQUERIES 1 AND 2 (UNION ALL)
```

Comment: Have you tried this query in SQLite? I'm getting a syntax error on those parens.

Comment: @rutter - sorry, too much Mssql lately. Fixed.